# How do I fix a call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object?

Tags: php

The code below gives me the following error:

> member function fetch_assoc() on non-object

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname="lamp";
$conn = new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) 
{
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$eventid=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_GET['eventid']);
$days=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_GET['days']);
$query=("select ID from agenda where eventid=?");   
$stmt=$conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("i",$eventid);    
$stmt->execute();   
$stmt->store_result();
$row=$stmt->num_rows;
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while($rows=$result->fetch_assoc())
{}
```

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to fetch on the $stmt not on the result, wich is a boolean result of your $stmt->get_result()

Use this

```
$result = $stmt->get_result();
if($result)
{
    while($rows = $stmt->fetch_assoc())
    {
    //Code here 
    }
}
```

Comment: but $stmt->get_result(); statment returns mi false

Comment: Certainly because you have trouble with your sql statement.